# characters being replaced/removed when running in browser?

Tags: php, html, browser

I have this website html page (.php file), and at some point I have this php script (Take a good look at the input's onclick attribute, as the problem revolves around there): The full php script is at the bottom at the post.

```
<?php
    require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."my-site/Database/db_connection.php"; 
    /*Some code was here.*/
    while($Student=$Result->fetch_row()){
        echo "<input class='Content_Link' id='".$Student[0]."' type='button' value='".$Student[1]." ".$Student[2]."' onclick='redirecter('.''.')'/>";
    }
/*normally a url would be passed into redirecter. To simplify the code during debugging, 
I have removed the url*/
    mysqli_free_result($Result);
    $Conn->close();
    /*a little more code*/
?>
```

The button is displaying correctly, however...
When the button is pressed, I get an unexpected token }, a rather simple error, until I compare the code in my text editor to the code in browser's developer tool.

Furthermore, addressing the unexpected token, after thoroughly checking all { } pairs in the php script and all required/included files inside the script (3+ times). All pairs are accounted for and completed. No extra brackets were found.

So far I have tried the website in microsoft edge, google chrome and firefox. They are all showing weird things with the onclick attribute:

text editor -

```
<input class='Content_Link' id='".$Student[0]."' type='button' value='".$Student[1]." ".$Student[2]."' onclick='redirecter('.''.')'/>
```

(With the php values placed directly in:)

```
<input class='Content_Link' id='2' type='button' value='Tyler Breau' onclick='redirecter('.''.')'/>
```

Chrome -

```
<input class="Content_Link" id="2" type="button" value="Tyler Breau" onclick="redirecter(" .''.')'>
```

Firefox -

```
<input id="2" class="Content_Link" value="Tyler Breau" onclick="redirecter(" .''.')'="" type="button"></input>
```

Microsoft Edge (Weirdest of them all) -

```
<input class="Content_Link" id="2" onclick="redirecter(" type="button" .''.')'="" value="Tyler Breau" />
```

The differences:

At

```
onclick='redirecter('.''.')'/>
```

the browsers' developer tools are displaying this as following common difference:

```
onclick="redirector(" .''.')'>
```

The first single quot: ' in the brackets is being placed by a double quot followed by a space: " . Furthermore, the forward slash for ending the input tag is being removed. '/> becomes '>

Firefox got a little more funky by adding ="" to the end of redirecter:

```
"redirecter(" .''.')'=""
```

And Microsoft Edge even more funky by placing the type="button" in side the redirecter brackets:

```
"redirecter(" type="button" .''.')'=""
```

My question... What in the world is going on? How do you even begin debugging this...

Programs/Version/etc I am using:

Sublime 3

Apache 2.4.17 (all in package from http://www.wampserver.com/en/ )

PHP 7

HTML5

Full php script:

Included and Required code are encased in commented out include (start) and 'End Include' or 'End Require' (end). An example is present at the very start of the php script.

```
<?php 
    //include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."my-site/General/get_user_type.php";
        require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."my-site/Database/db_connection.php";//No brackets are present in file
        if(!(isset($_SESSION))){
            session_start();
        }
        $Result=mysqli_query($Conn, "SELECT Type FROM user_accounts WHERE ID=".$_SESSION["uid"]);
        $Type=$Result->fetch_object()->Type;
        mysqli_free_result($Result);
        $Conn->close();
    //End include
    if($Type === "Admin"){
        echo "<div class='Sub_Content' id='div_Student_List'>
                <p class='Sub_Content_Title'> Student List </p>

                <input class='Content_Link_Viewer' id='btn_Student_List' type='button' value='show' name='div_Students' onclick='displayContent(this.id, this.value)'/>
                <p class='Content_Link_Describer'> - Students </p><br/>
                <div class='Content_Link_Holder' id='div_Students'>";
                    //require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."my-site/Home_Page/student_list.php";
                        require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."my-site/Database/db_connection.php";//No brackets are present in this file
                        $Result=mysqli_query($Conn,"SELECT Class_Code FROM user_accounts WHERE ID=".$_SESSION["uid"]);
                        if($Result===false){
                            $Conn->close();
                            $Student_List="Oops! Failed to get Student List";
                        }else{
                            $Class_Code=$Result->fetch_object()->Class_Code;
                            mysqli_free_result($Result);
                            $Result=mysqli_query($Conn,"SELECT Student_ID, Student_First_Name, Student_Last_Name FROM student_list WHERE Class_Code='$Class_Code'");
                            if($Result===false){
                                $Conn->close();
                                $Student_List="Oops! Failed to get Student List";
                            }else{
                                while($Student=$Result->fetch_row()){
/*Problem button here*/             echo "<input class='Content_Link' id='".$Student[0]."' type='button' value='".$Student[1]." ".$Student[2]."' onclick='redirecter('.''.')'/>";
                                }
                                mysqli_free_result($Result);
                                $Conn->close();
                            }
                        }
                    //End Require
        echo    "</div>
            </div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What this is supposed to be: `redirecter('.''.')`? It is funky by itself.

Comment: a url is post to be there, I removed the url to simplify it. Forgot to add that little note xD. I'll do that right now.

Comment: Try to use escaped double quote `onclick=\"redirecter(\".\"\".\")\"`

Comment: Looks normal in the developer tools now. Thanks! I wonder what caused the browsers to act so weirdly though....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by sTx at this comment: [characters being replaced/removed when running in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639479/characters-being-replaced-removed-when-running-in-browser?noredirect=1#comment64662641_38639479)

escaping double-quotes in the redirecter() fixed the really weird behavior.